# Incrementing the values in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, increment

I am trying to separate a group of values into bins for a histogram chart. There will be 10 bins in my histogram. To sort and count the number of cases in each bin, I am using an array. The error I am getting is `The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer`. idx will give me the bin number that needs to be incremented. I am just unsure of the proper way to increment it. Thank you for the suggestions and comments.

```
            int binsize = Convert.ToInt32(xrLabel101.Text) / 10;//Max divided by 10 to get the size of each bin
            this.xrChart4.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            int binCount = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < binCount; i++)
            {
                int m = Convert.ToInt32(xrLabel104.Text);//This is the number of loops needed
                string[] binct = new string[10];

                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                {
                    int idx = Convert.ToInt32(currentcolumnvalue) / binsize;
                    binct[idx]++;//I know this is wrong. Suggestions?
                }

            }
```

Comment: What is the data type of binct?

Comment: I created the array to keep count of the number of cases in each of 10 bins. It can just be an integer.

Comment: See Tigran's answer. You're accessing the object at index 'idx' in the code above, which is a string array. You can't increment a string array. I assume you're trying to do something with k in that for loop as well?

Comment: The k is the number of cases to be sorted. I am just using it to loop the appropriate number of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple: the type returned by your expression `binct[idx]` does not support numerical
operation like `++`, `+` `-`...

To avoid this there are at last a couple of ways:

- [Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- Execute the same operation on other type then this and map the result to type you want.

Comment: So I can just change it to int[] binct = new int[10]?

Comment: @RolandP: if you change the array you have now to `int[]`, sure you can do arithmetic operations on the elements of it, as they are integers.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

```
            int binsize = Convert.ToInt32(xrLabel101.Text) / 10;//Max divided by 10 to get the size of each bin
            this.xrChart4.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            int binCount = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < binCount; i++)
            {
                int m = Convert.ToInt32(xrLabel104.Text);//This is the number of loops needed
                int[] binct = new int[10];

                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                {
                    int idx = Convert.ToInt32(currentcolumnvalue) / binsize;
                    binct[idx] = binct[idx] + 1;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to increment a string which makes no sense. Make your array an array of int instead